# Why do some airlines ask for the reason for travel when booking domestic flights within the US?

Tags: usa, bookings, airlines, alaska-airlines

Why do some airlines ask for the reason for travel when booking domestic flights within the US?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Does your employer have a preferred fare agreement?

Comment: @littleadv Sorry I am not sure if I can publish that information, but that could perhaps be a good reason to ask for the travel reason indeed.

Comment: @littleadv This seems to be quite late in the booking process, I would be surprised if at that stage the selection changed anything.

Comment: Often, when you finish going through the reservation steps and paying, the airline site will bring up a screen offering you deals with their partners "See these hotel deals in San Jose" or something like that.  That choice (business or pleasure) may filter which deals get offered.

Answer (score 21):

As far as I know this is purely a marketing question, and will usually be optional.

You can find such questions on airline websites but also hotels, railways, and more, in many countries. In most cases the question is asked during the booking process, sometimes they ask the question upfront in search parameters (in which case it may have an influence on what fare types they put forward).

Apparently the answer to that question is useful to them for reporting, to optimise their yield management, communication campaigns and whatnot.

It may have an influence on what additional services they put forward, or they may take that into account in overbooking ratios.

Another possible reason is that some agency at either end wants the info for their own statistics.

On some sites/apps this allows the user to filter past bookings (so if you use the same account for business and personal trips, you can easily find the business ones for your expense reports), or may change the payment method (e.g. Uber allows one to save one payment card for personal and another for business), but in the latter case this is usually quite a bit more explicit.

Comment: In some countries, if you're travelling for business, you are exempt from city tax at hotels

Comment: @NicolasFormichella [Which countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/183141/1810)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be optional in the OP's screenshot - there's apparently no way to submit the form without answering the question. Maybe the airline considers it acceptable for customers to give a false answer.

Comment: @bdsl at the bottom of the screen it says that required fields have red asterisk. No red asterisk, it should be optional. I suppose by default neither option is selected, and that OP selected one OP before taking the screenshot. What the UI lacks is a way to cancel the selection.

Comment: @jcaron Right. I think good UI design generally requires always having a radio button selected by default if radio buttons are used.

Comment: @bdsl If you pre-select anything then you have the risk people leaving it as is, end you end up with more incorrect (rather than just incomplete) data, or, if you give them three explicit choices (A/B/not your business) and you preselect the "not your business" option, then more people will keep that one, so more incomplete data. I believe the 2 options with none pre-selected are actually the best choice to optimize the chances of (a) getting an answer (many people will think they have to answer even if it's optional) and (b) getting the right answer.

Comment: @jcaron Commonly understood UI/UX usage dictates that radio buttons should be pre-populated with a default value.  And that is the whole point of the entire HTML radio button analogy to .. radio buttons.

Comment: @PeterM: The radio buttons I remember from actual radios had an ”off” button that popped back up, so none were selected.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy the radio buttons that served as the model for UI radio buttons were the tuning buttons.  The radio was turned on and off by rotating the volume control knob.

Comment: @PeterM the radio-button user interface paradigm arose many years (decades, in fact) before HTML.  Of course, everyone says "When a button was pressed, all other buttons would pop out, leaving the pressed button the only button in the "pushed down" state," but that's not actually how they worked.

Comment: @phoog You shouldn't conflate the idea with the implementation.  And yes, been there, done that with car and other radios.  However, changing an entrenched paradigm isn't the best response to a (potentially) bad UI design.